# How to use @Pathvariable and @RequestParam at the same time in Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm trying to provide a rest service in spring-boot in order to match requests like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/customer/v1/user/1/purchase?productId=2
```

So, I've created a service like this :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/customer/v1/user/{userId}/purchase?productId={productId}")
public ResponseDto Test(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,@RequestParam("productId") String productId ){
    return  new ResponseDto();
}
```

But it seems it does not match the request and I get this error :

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase]
Looking up handler method for path /customer/v1/user/1/purchase
Did not find handler method for [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase]
Matching patterns for request [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase] are [/**]
URI Template variables for request [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase] are {}
Mapping [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]],
Last-Modified value for [/customer/v1/user/1/purchase] is: -1
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
Looking up handler method for path /error
Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
Written [{timestamp=Mon Oct 29 17:52:20 IRST 2018, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/customer/v1/user/1/purchase}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@bb8ead8]
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
```

I've tried different way including using @RequestParam at Controller-Level, But still no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's complaining about you defining the parameters in your `GetMapping`. This works fine:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/customer/v1/user/{userId}/purchase")
public ResponseDto Test(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,@RequestParam("productId") String productId ){
    return  new ResponseDto();
}
```

It will automatically put the value after `productId` in the url in the `productId` variable.

If you wanted to add `@RequestParam` elements which are not always required you can define them like this: `@RequestParam(value = "count", required=false) String count`, notice the `required` part? Spring will throw an error if you define it as required and you're not passing it in the url. You could also define the `defaultValue` which will solve your issue aswell. See [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But it doesn't support multiple query parameter. What I wanted to reach is something like this : http://localhost:8080/customer/v1/user/1/purchase?productId=2&count=3

Comment: How does it not support it? Can you not just put `@RequestParam("count")` as extra parameter in the function?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work, I tried and i get this error : MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'count' for method parameter of type String

Comment: @Mostafa I've updated the answer to include explanation of optional `@RequestParam` elements.

Comment: This also works for message mapping. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the "productId" in the value of @GetMapping. It will be automatically picked up.